# Identifying the cause of NOT ST_IsValid()

Tags: postgis

I have a table of raw GeoJSON in a Postgres database, with PostGIS installed.  Some of this GeoJSON is unfortunately invalid, for varying reasons.

```
SELECT
    id, name, geometry
FROM shapes
WHERE
    NOT ST_IsValid(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geometry));
```

Sample log output:

```
NOTICE:  Self-intersection at or near point -98.12763909659509 40.524842899558408
NOTICE:  Ring Self-intersection at or near point -89.500197172165002 45.280231548720003
NOTICE:  Nested shells at or near point -80.15264234 34.224868579999999
NOTICE:  Duplicate Rings at or near point -80.155240000000006 34.217115999999997
NOTICE:  IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 3 - must be 0 or >= 4
NOTICE:  IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1 elements
```

Self-intersection is by far the most common error.  I'd like to edit out the self-intersection completely, such as via [`ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology.html).  However, when I attempt to do so:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    geometry,
    ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geometry), .00000001)) as new_geometry
FROM shapes
WHERE
    NOT ST_IsValid(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geometry));
```

Those `IllegalArgumentExceptions` kill the query:

```
ERROR:  First argument geometry could not be converted to GEOS: IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 3 - must be 0 or >= 4
```

I tried using [`ST_IsSimple`](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_IsSimple.html) to filter those geometries out, but that function also triggers an `IllegalArgumentException`.

How can I more accurately identify which validity error a GeoJSON string suffers from so that I can filter out those nastier geometries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, in general, use Postgis operations on invalid geometries. So something like simplification (as you've tried) won't work.

What you can try is [ST_MakeValid](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeValid.html).

However that is not going to magically give you back correct data. It will usually provide back dimensionally-valid data, but that may not be what you expect. In particular, note these two statements from the documentation:

> In case of full or partial dimensional collapses, the output geometry
>   may be a collection of lower-to-equal dimension geometries or a
>   geometry of lower dimension.
>
> Single polygons may become multi-geometries in case of
>   self-intersections.

So you need to closely check the data after making it valid.

Comment: Clarifications: Yes, most Postgis operations do not work on invalid geometries, but `ST_Simplify` will work fine, unless you have an `IllegalArgumentException`.  The problem is, simplify does a poor job of repairing self intersection while preserving accuracy. `ST_MakeValid` therefore is more preferred, but often at the cost of ugly MultiPolygon results.  Bad data either way.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should probably be using [`ST_IsValidDetail`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValidDetail.html) rather than just `ST_IsValid`.  That way you can decide how to treat each group of invalid geometries individually.

So in your query to simplify the self intersections should be something like

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    geometry,
    ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geometry), .00000001)) as new_geometry
FROM shapes
WHERE
    reason(ST_IsValidDetail(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geometry))) = 'Self-intersection';
```

Comment: You can also use [`ST_IsValidReason`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_IsValidReason.html).

Comment: `ST_IsValidReason` is perfect - indicating a self-intersection and why; `ST_IsValidDetail` returns `t,,` which is difficult to understand (especially when `ST_IsValid` returns `f`. Do you know why?

Comment: @BradKoch I agree ST_IsValidReason would be better.

Comment: @David I'm not seeing that behaviour from ST_IsValidDetail.  I'm using 2.1.3 at the moment

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to filter the query based on validity type via SQL.  What you do have, due to the `NOT ST_IsValid` condition, is a pair of equal length ordered lists of invalid geometry notices and geometries.

These two lists can be manually correlated to identify which error each geometry suffers from.  Filter out any `IllegalArgumentException`, and other queries should be able to execute.